# Exception creating bean of class org.apache.struts.validator.DynaValidatorForm

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications, struts, oc4j

When accessing a JSP page the following exception is thrown:

```
Exception creating bean of class org.apache.struts.validator.DynaValidatorForm
```

Other actions that use this class too are working fine.

Unfortunately we don't know at what problem this exception does hint. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out it was a class loader problem. The same application was deployed two times.

We could have seen it in the log files all along.

Answer (score 2):

Try this it worked for me once :
Change

```
<form-bean name="deptForm" type="org.apache.struts.action.DynaValidatorForm">
```

to

```
<form-bean name="deptForm" type="org.apache.struts.[B]validator[/B].DynaValidatorForm">
```

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the `.class` file is generated or not in the classes folder.
Some times it happens when you just copy and paste your Java Class and it can't find the class at the time of build.